# boost работа с датой и временем одновременно С++

Tags: c++, boost

В одном из классов мне необходимо фиксировать дату + время. Я хочу это сделать в одном поле, но ни `boost::posix_time::ptime` ни `boost::gregorian::date` мне не предоставляет такой возможности (а возможно и предоставляет, поэтому я здесь).
Суть таски в том, чтобы искать объект по дата+время, который я должна задать САМА.
Я могу сгенерить время+дата при создании объекта так:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

boost::posix_time::ptime CreationTime = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
```

и выведется мне что-то типа: `2020-Dec-23 03:56:46`

Круто. Как создать переменную, допустим, в мейне, с таким же типом, но самой указать параметры(дату и время)?
Жду любого работающего примера. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот написал вспомогательную функцию `CreatePTime(...)` и с помощью её в main() задаю заданную дату из строки и формата времени.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##fVBNT4QwEL3zKyYYTElgl2U9VeTixYuJiV48bdjSXSeBltAhmhh/O7Z8ZFldnUM78@bN1xNNE4uqUMe@v0Ilqq6UkFVaFJXMvRNiDLWyqM8galEdlwjq36y9tuC6LEjuCGu5brTBj5/u6q1pcs8buJyfcOu7D@5tV5JPL9ZnhkrOx9kgtDIE12AcK4JLqUNNIXx6YG1Ij6dNaRvA3RJnC59zq4sxKFgYDfXOlHyHC2u6d4eq6Wh3KIQk5saGt6exOK416gNo2LDyxECzwnrfSWYHT9CfUtBcAnk@B62krlUu@vI8VAR1gYrNZ/@vKmrlZLUyLEX20yRN4k0ap1tINjxJ@fbGj8APXuOgjoMSggcePPLg2V8eKXRHkGXnjW08JKUqK7dg338D)

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime CreatePTime(std::string const & stime, std::string const & fmt) {
    std::locale const loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(),
        new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(fmt));
    std::istringstream is(stime);
    is.imbue(loc);
    boost::posix_time::ptime t;
    is >> t;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    boost::posix_time::ptime CreationTime = CreatePTime("2020-12-23 01:02:34", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    std::cout << CreationTime << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
2020-Dec-23 01:02:34
```